# Change css class depending on label's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have `asp:Table` with number of `asp:Label` inside `asp:FormView`, it represents short stats info.

I need to set `Label.CssClass` to "red" if it's text isn't "0".

Currently I do this on `FormView.DataBound` event. But think that it's better to use `JavaScript` and probably `jQuery`. How can I do that?

Sorry for dummy question - I'm new to jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery (you can also give the Table or FormView a class, probably easier in aps.net instead of the `ID` like I have below):

```
$("#formViewOrTableID span").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() !== "0";
}).addClass("redClass");
```

If you give the labels a class you want affected, say set all the Labels you want included to `CssClass="styleMe"`, you could change `$("#formViewID span")` to
`$("#formViewID span.styleMe")` to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks! And what is the most appropriate way to attach call of this function as on server-side event like `DataBound` or `Load`?

Comment: @abatishchev - Are you in an `UpdatePanel` or just need it to run when the page loads?

Comment: No, I don't use. Yea, just want to try to load when page loads.

Comment: @abatishchev - jQuery provides this functionality, either inside `<script tyle="text/javascript"></script>` in your page, or in an external `.js` file, just take what I have above and wrap it in `$(function() { ...answer code here... });`, this will execute it when the page is ready on the client, no server-side code needed.